# Sed operation fails when typical variable expansion is implemented ${domain}

Tags: php, bash, sed, replace

Consider the following code:

```
read domain
    > old-domain.com
```

and then:

```
sed -i 's/${domain}/new-domain.com'/g /var/www/html/test/wp-config.php
```

The `sed` operation fails - no change would occur on all instances of ${domain} in the wp-config.php file... For example, the following code won't change:

define('DB_NAME', 'old-domain.com');

In other words, `old-domain.com` (represented in `${domain}`), won't change to `new-domain.com`, after the `sed` operation. Why is that?

Note: I don't see anything to escape in my `sed` operation and has no errors.

Comment: Use only double quotes in your `sed`. Your variable `$domain` does not get expanded in single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash`, there's a difference between single quote and double quote strings: Only in double-quote strings do environment variables get expanded.

Try it:

```
$ echo "${USER}"
$ echo '${USER}'
```

Replace the single quotes with double quotes and try again.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this command does nothing:

```
$ sed 's/${domain}/new-domain.com'/g wp-config.php
define('DB_NAME', 'old-domain.com');
```

But this command works:

```
$ sed  "s/${domain}/new-domain.com"/g wp-config.php
define('DB_NAME', 'new-domain.com');
```

Add back the `-i` option to change the file in place.

The issue is that shells, including bash, do not expand variables when they are inside single-quotes.  Your command will work if you switch to double-quotes.

Note that, if `$domain` contains sed-active characters, you may get surprising or even dangerous results.  So, don't use this unless you are confident in what values will be assigned to `domain`.

#### Safer alternative

Consider using awk as follows:

```
$ awk -v old="${domain}" '{gsub(old, "new-domain.com")} 1' wp-config.php
define('DB_NAME', 'new-domain.com');
```

When run like this, awk will treat `$doman` *as data not code* and this avoids many of the potential pitfalls of the sed approach.

If you have GNU awk, you can change the file in-place with:

```
awk -i inplace -v old="${domain}" '{gsub(old, "new-domain.com")} 1' wp-config.php
```

Alternatively, for any awk, use:

```
awk -v old="${domain}" '{gsub(old, "new-domain.com")} 1' wp-config.php >tmp && mv tmp wp-config.php
```

Comment: Thank you John. Just one small thing. You told me to bring back the `-i` option but you didn't include it in your own example. If I understand correct `-i` prints what's being done with `sed` to my current console.

Comment: @Arcticooling You're welcome.  `-i` means change the file in-place *instead of* sending it to standard output.  If you want to see the changes on the screen, do *not* use `-i`.  (Are you on Mac or Linux?  When using `-i`, there is a subtle difference between the two on how `-i` operates.)

Comment: Hmm, I use Ubuntu server 16.04.

Comment: @Arcticooling Then no problem.  To update the file in place, use `-i` just as you were using it.  To see things on the screen, omit `-i`.